# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Queue' while using docker-compse

Tags: python-2.7, docker-compose, configparser

This is test code.
My code works fine in local environment. When do a docker-compose configParser fails to identify any section.
This is the output from docker

```
app_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1      |   File "app/test.py", line 5, in <module>
app_1      |     host=conf.get("Queue","host")
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
app_1      |     raise NoSectionError(section)
app_1      | ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'Queue'
```

While the code is:

```
import ConfigParser
conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
conf.read("env.conf")
host=conf.get("Queue","host")
```

If i get into bash of the container and execute python test.py then the config works fine in reading the Queue section.
Help me figure out whats happening here.